# Smarty reading config values from .conf files in PHP

Tags: php, smarty

For a meeting schedule, I want to have dynamic pages for any given room. User can edit a file named "schedules.conf" in the config folder. At the moment it looks like this:

```
[rooms]
room = 5022
room = 5082
```

And I can load it normally and it shows 2 links in my web page:

```
{config_load file="schedules.conf" section="rooms"}
......
......
......

{foreach from=#room# item=r}

<li><span><span><a href="{$smarty.const.SITE_URL}/admin/schedules.list.php?room={$r}">Schedules {$r}</a></span></span></li>                    

{/foreach}
```

So it links to the handler PHP file, now in the php file I want to check weather that room exist in the config file, so if someone manually change the GET value for room in the address bar I could have a chance to handle that:

```
  if(!isset($_GET["room"]))
  {
      header('location: '.SITE_URL.'/admin/index.php');
  }
  else
  {
      $validRooms = $smarty->getConfigDir();

      //How to check id the $_GET["room"] value exist in the config file      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep this page [Conditional checks using smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl) for isset()

EDIT

In light of comment #1 by the OP:

How about use a conditional check along with `in_array($_GET['room'], $validRooms)`

Comment: That I know, but I want to strictly check in my PHP file and if room number does exist only then I pull data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Check by this way: Use in_array() function

```
$room = array(5022,5082);
if (in_array($_GET['room'], $room)) {
    // you can pull the data from database
}else{
die('Wrong room data');
}
```

Comment: Might be a soloution but not really...I want end uses only edit the config file. This way I should put this $room array in php file and ask users to edit that later as well.

Comment: in that case you can encode the room data and send through url and fetch both the value from url one is the normal value and other is a encoded value then decode it and match, if matches then pull the data otherwise show error msg.

Comment: @Sikander Checking against another, equally untrusted, user input variable won't provide any protection against manually editing the URL. There has to be some secret known only on the server, and the config file is currently that secret.

Comment: @Sikander I was referring to your comment "in that case you can encode the room data and send through url and fetch both the value from url" - it sounded like you were suggesting putting two variables on the URL, and then comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Luckly I got an answer from Smarty forum administrator: Here is how to do it:

Instead of loading the config file in the template you can load it in the PHP script.

See [Config load API](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.config.load.tpl)

After that you can read the config vars

See [Config vars](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.config.vars.tpl)